# Graph between PV & P, Boyle's Law and its interpretation

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, phase

My text book says:

> At higher constant temperature, the volume increase and value of product PV should increase due to increase of volume at same pressure, but PV remains constant at this new temperature & a straight  line is obtained parallel to pressure axis in the fig

[image: I could not get the idea if, this is a boyle's law then why pressure remains same instead of temperature?]

I could not get the idea if, this is a Boyle's law then why pressure remains same instead of temperature?

Comment: What is your exact question?

Answer (score 0):

That's the graph you get under **isothermal** conditions.

Recall the ideal gas equation of state:

$$PV = nRT$$

At isothermal conditions, temperature is constant (duh!), so as a result the $PV$ term is going to be constant as well. You may as well try changing the volume of your gas container, but pressure will just adjust itself to make sure $PV$ remains the same.